# allow child folder in .hgignore

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Does anyone know if it is possible to ignore a parent-folder in Mercurial and allow a child-folder to commit.
I have a folder structure like this

```
www.Project.com
01 – Consultancy
02 – Information Architecture
03 – Content
04 – Branding
    Fonts
    Guidelines
    Logo
05 – Design
    Graphics
    Stock Photography
06 – Code
    Static site
    Wordpress
07 – Marketing
    Email
    SEO
    Social Media
```

And I like to ignore the Wordpress folder except;

```
06 - Code\Worpdress\wp-content\plugins  
06 - Code\Worpdress\wp-content\themes
```

I am also using a code to ignore a global folder

```
syntax: glob  
01 - Ignore/**
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was going to suggest you use regular expressions (they are supported in hg ignore file). But unfortunately, official documentation suggests against it, and in general claims that this feature is not supported:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore

> Limitations
>
> There is no straightforward way to ignore all but a set of files. Attempting to use an inverted regex match will fail when combined with other patterns. This is an intentional limitation, as alternate formats were all considered far too likely to confuse users to be worth the additional flexibility.

My personal opinion is that it is better to separate generated/ignored folders and "real"/tracked folders. Then your deployment script can upload/copy plugins/themes from tracked folder to the deployment folder.

Or, if it is practical, just include files/folders one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use [mercurial subrepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/subrepos) for the plugins and themes directories to have fine-grained control over what is tracked and what not.